# Dissolve animation for single view in iOS

Tags: ios, animation, avplayer

I have a view and on that there is a `AVPlayer` on that I need a dissolve animation when the player is
moving from the first video to second video.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your UIView structure, but you can load the new UIView / AVVideo and use UIView animations to transform the current view to the second one.

```
// load new UIView
// make it invisible
[UIView animateWithDuration:1
                      delay:1.5
                    options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                     // fade in, or change x/y to slide in
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
```